# Retro fitting a website for mobile friendliness

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Like many people I suspect, I have an existing website that I am trying to modify so it works well on much smaller mobile screens. I am happy to make a great deal of concessions in order to do this. However my main problem is the site's logo. Happy to swap it out for something small and static, but what I have in the original site is a Flash file for the logo. Yes, big mistake but then hindsight is a marvelous thing. What I have to deal with is a logo which is:

```
> * Specified in an external style sheet
> * Specified in an external XML file
> * Has additional hard coding in the HTML (size, placement etc)
> * Has an actual external Flash file too of course
```

So my historical decision to go with Flash has consequences in at least four different kinds of file as well as every HTML and PHP page in the site.

My question then is what is the minimally disruptive way I can modify the existing site to specify something smaller and simpler than I have at the moment? I am happy to not have the Flash file feature in the mobile site, if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a web technology I was not previously familiar with called "media queries" and I urge anyone unfamiliar with the concept to Google it and find a good primer. In a nutshell, media queries allow you to insert a section in your style sheet that queries the maximum (or minimum) screen resolution of the device your site is being viewed on and specify an alternative set of styling instructions for that event. It's like introducing an If/Else construct to your style sheet.

In my case I simply created an alternative logo - smaller and a static .jpg image. Then I worked out the screen size threshold below which I wanted the smaller logo to appear in, and then wrote my media query, which looks like this:

```
@media screen 
and (max-device-width: 1023px) { 
         #flashContent { display:none; }
         #altlogo { background-image: url("/images/mobile_logo.jpg"); width: 318px; height: 43px; margin-left: 2%; margin-bottom: 1px;} 
}
```

The first part says not to show the Flash logo, while the second specicies an alternative. Of course you also need to create a hook inside the HTML for this to operate, hence adding the following div right after the original flashContent div:

```
<div id="altlogo" role="img" aria-label="My Smaller logo"></div>
```

Note I don't want to stray too far from my original question into the realms of an extensive introduction to media queries, but I will add that the parameters to my additional div serve as a way round the accessibility issue of being unable to add an 'alt' tag to the substitute logo image. Screen readers will detect and read out these parameters in lieu of an alt tag. There are other issues unaddressed here such as loading two logos when you only display one, but these are completely solvable issues that are beyond the remit of my original question to address here which I leave to interested parties to research.